# Mongoose schema method returning is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

```
userSchema.method.comparePassword = async function(enteredPassword){
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
}
```

So in the above code I have a mongoose User schema method in for my users database for comparing the encrypted passwords stored in my database each time a user tries to login.

```
const ispasswordMatched = await User.comparePassword(password);
```

In this code is where I call this method in the controler but each time I make a request with postman, it returns an error saying User.comparePassword is not a function. I've searched for a while about others experiencing this but nothing could solve my problem and it left me baffled on how to proceed about solving this. Any advice or tips is greatly apriciated.
Quick edit I am using mongodb version 4.4 with mongoose version 5.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a typo, you're missing the "s" after `method`. Try this:

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(enteredPassword){
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
}
```

Mongoose document [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is already answered but I had the same problem and it fixed by using `findOne()` instead of `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to use it like the referred method in the mongoose docs

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-method

where mentioning the name is an argument for the method function.Not like what you have done here
eg.
const schema = kittySchema = new Schema(..);

```
 schema.method('meow', function () {
 console.log('meeeeeoooooooooooow');
 })

 const Kitty = mongoose.model('Kitty', schema);

 const fizz = new Kitty;
      fizz.meow();
```

Comment: Tried it, returned same error, Another quick edit I've seen some people suggest I make a backup and reinstall mongodb. I am relativly new to programing but woult you recommend this?

Comment: do that also , make sure you are using latest version of mongoose too. and check than. just confirming both methods are in the same js file right?

Comment: Reinstalling mongodb did the trick. Still not sure what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error in my code.. later on I realised that that my custom static schema method returns an array even when there is only a single document... the following code worked.

```
const user = await User.findByName("Meghna")
//user.sayHi() -> this one was failing with not a function error
user[0].sayHi() 
console.log(user)
```